# Understanding Permeation Units

Tags: pressure, measurements, gas

I have encountered a type of unit that I cannot understand. The unit describes the rate of permeation through a substance:(cm^3 . mm)/m^2 . d . atm

Could someone please explain how to interpret these units? Please attempt to leave the answer in simple - to - understand terms as chemistry, not engineering, is my primary field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{\left(\mbox{amount of gas}\right)\left(\mbox{thickness of membrane}\right)}
{\left(\mbox{membrane area}\right)\left(\mbox{time}\right)\left(\mbox{differential pressure of gas}\right)}
$$

[Units of gas permeability constants](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/app.1975.070190915/abstract) (source of the formula)
[Gas Barrier Introduction](http://www.soarnol.com/eng/solution/solution040507.html)
[Introduction to Material Permeability Indexes](http://en.labthink.com/en-us/literatures/detailed-introduction-to-material-permeability-indexes.html)